# Why my unity project with vuforia doesn't work on my smartphone?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to create an AR application using Vuforia instead of ARFoundation. I'm using Unity version 2022.3.11, and I've installed Vuforia Engine 10.18.4. I removed the main camera and replaced it with Vuforia's ARCamera. I've configured Vuforia and added the license key. I also added an image target with a specific 3D model. When I test it in 'play mode,' the application works, but when I build it for Android (both for the OnePlus Nord 2 with Android 13 and the Motorola Edge 20 Lite), it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to detect the image target at all. In the project settings, 'arm64' is checked, and 'arm7' is not. The Android API level is already set to Android 8.0. What could be the reason for this issue?

What I would expect is that when I point the AR app at the image, a 3D model should be overlaid on that image. However, what actually happens is that nothing appears.

Comment: I would try to start from the Vuforia Engine Unity sample and either crosscheck your configuration against the sample one or swap the sample target with yours https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples